# a node.js module that converts multipage tiff images

Tags: node.js, tiff

Is there any tool available to convert multipage tiff files to JPG,PNG..etc?

I was using sharp, a module from node.js to convert tiff images to the formats I wish. But it seems that it can't convert those single tiff file with multiple pages compressed (it converts just the first page)

Comment: [multipage tiff](https://superuser.com/questions/44600/how-to-split-a-multipage-tiff-file-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The Best module is imagemagick http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php. You can use this to do most image translations / conversions,

At a command prompt, just type ...

```
npm install imagemagick
npm install tiff-to-png
```

Comment: He asked for a node.js module.

Comment: I'll remove if you edit answer. I'm unable unless answers changed. Imagemagick is a command line binary, but he was asking for a nodejs specific module.

Comment: the answer is changed now

Answer (score 0):

Any node.js module is going to use ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick underneath, so you need these binary files on your `$PATH`. If you're using OSX, make sure you have the [brew package manager](https://brew.sh/), and then run:

```
brew install imagemagick
brew install graphicsmagick
```

Now, there's a simple node.js module [tiff-to-png](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiff-to-.) you can install:

```
$ npm install tiff-to-png
```

Then make a simple script like below:

```
const ConvertTiff = require('tiff-to-png');
const glob = require('glob');

// cwd option sets the current-working-directory
// that tiff-to-png runs from.
let options = {
  cwd: '/path/to/rootDir/of/tiffs'
};

let location = '/path/to/output/pictures';
let converter = new ConvertTiff(options);

// for Files
let forFiles = (err, files) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  converter.convertArray(files, location);
};

// glob it.
glob('**/*.tif', options, forFiles);
```

Now, if your multipage tif files are not being split properly. There are two commands you should have after installing the imagemagick and graphicsmagick libraries: `tiffcp` and `tiffsplit`.

Sometimes it is improper compression that causes the failure you're seeing. Use `tiffcp -c none orig.tif fixed.tif` to remove troublesome compression. Then run `tiffsplit fixed.tif prefixForSplitFile-` and you should get multiple files in a multipage tiff.

Finally, for converting to formats outside PNG, and for more advanced image processing with Image/GraphicsMagick using node.js install the [gm](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) module, which can run the above commands all from node.js.